# Getting Server Error while fetching images from get request of ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, web

While Executing Ajax get request to fetch image from another view of mvc asp.net getting the following console error, function is not hitting the success method  :

```
"GET http://localhost:1879/cardimages/getimage?id=12 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

Below I am adding all three code snippets of controller, ajax call and view code of dropdown , through which i am trying to fetch the image from db

I am trying to fetch image from dropdown selection in asp.net mvc :

Following is AJAX code :

```
$(function () {
    $("#ImageId").change(function (evt) {
        var DropDownSelectedVal = $("#ImageId :selected").val();
        alert(DropDownSelectedVal);
        if (DropDownSelectedVal != null) {
            alert("Success");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetImage", "CardImages")",
                type: "Get",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "Image",
                data: {id: DropDownSelectedVal},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                    $("img-upload2").attr('src', data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Following is function in controller :

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id /* drop down value */)
{
    var cardImage = db.CardImages.Where(x=>x.CityId == id ).FirstOrDefault();
    string dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFilesPath1"].ToString() + "/";
    string logoPath = GetFileFromFolder(dir, cardImage.CardFileName + cardImage.OriginalFileName);
    if (logoPath != string.Empty)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(logoPath);
        cardImage.LogoImage = "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
    //var model = db.CardImages.Find(id); // This is for example put your code to fetch record.
    //ViewBag.img = (from s in db.CardImages where s.CityId == id select s.CardFileName + s.OriginalFileName);
    return Json(cardImage.LogoImage);
}
```

And in view this for dropdown i am using

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityId", null,  "Select City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @Id = "ImageId" })
```

I am getting browser error in alert as Something went wrong and console error as mentioned above.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) - that's mean the error is on the server-side, not on your jquery client-side.

Comment: Try to debug your server code and find the issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Rajesh

Comment: Open your browser console and switch to the network tab and make an ajax call. In the list you should now see your file with red text. Click on it and it will show a preview of the response from the server. That will help you to try and narrow down your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#ImageId").change(function (evt) {
        var DropDownSelectedVal = $("#ImageId :selected").val();
        alert(DropDownSelectedVal);
        if (DropDownSelectedVal != null) {
            alert("Success");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetImage", "CardImages")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json;charset-utf-8",
                data: "{'id':'" + DropDownSelectedVal+ "'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                    $("img-upload2").attr('src', data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```